# JSDuck - Created document that doesn't show any parameters of function

Tags: javascript, jsduck

Example:
There are several .js files with couple functions like:

```
/**
 * TestFunction - doing something.
 * @param {String} strTest Test string.
 * @return {Boolean} bRes Returned value.
 */
function TestFunction(strTest) {
   //code ...
   return bRes;
}
```

After JsDuck.exe created help file - no parameters of function in function description is present, only return value bRes with description.
Version: SDuck 5.0.0.beta2 also tried on earlier version and same result.

Does anyone used JSduck for functional frameworks and got success. or are there any workaround to get this work properly?

Same .js files work correctly with JSDoc toolkit and all data is shown, but JSDuck is still preferable to make it work.

Thanks in advance for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered your question in bug-tracker: https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/issues/358